# Date format in a table SAPUI5

Tags: date, odata, sapui5

I have created a table using SAPUI5 and I get the data to the table using ODATA service. BUt, I have a column which is of a type `DATE` and the format is something like this `"Thu Jan 13 2011 01:00:00 GMT+0100 (Mitteleuropäische Zeit)"`.

I tried to google and I found [this](http://scn.sap.com/community/developer-center/front-end/blog/2013/04/28/working-with-odata-dates) blog which is really nice.

But here I see also a [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/cika/1/edit) example where only a single data value has been used. But I need to select one whole column  "`Businessdate`" and format it to something like this ´13.01.2014´. Any suggestions?

The data in my source table is of type `DATE`.

Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to Add Date / Time from OData Service Correctly to UI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47593990/how-to-add-date-time-from-odata-service-correctly-to-ui)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have updated your jsbin example: http://jsbin.com/cika/4/edit

The changes I've made:

1. I have mimicked your ODate date's ISO8601 format by just setting it to the current date:

   ```
   oModel.setData({
       dateValue:  new Date() // I.e. Mon Feb 24 2014 17:35:22 GMT+0100 (W. Europe Standard Time)
   });
   ```
2. Just let the DatePicker control format it to your desired output format ('dd-MM-yyyy'):

   ```
   new sap.ui.commons.DatePicker("date2",{
       width: "10em",
       value: {
           path: "myModel>/dateValue",
           //the format information 
           type: new sap.ui.model.type.Date({pattern: "dd.MM.yy"})
       }
   });
   ```

Hope this helps!